# Httpresponse Error 503

Tags: c#, http, httpwebrequest, cloudflare, http-status-code-503

I'm trying to download a web page data from a website that is hosted by CloudFlare. It uses HTTPS and gets ID for the connection before getting into the page.

I'm trying to get the id in WebRequest and WebResponse but I'm getting the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll
>   Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.

I tried to make the request from Fiddler and here is the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable
Date: Tue, 12 May 2015 13:38:17 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d57a7d982035dad7ebafe63444d125e451431437897; expires=Wed, 11-May-16 13:38:17 GMT; path=/; domain=.hornystress.me; HttpOnly
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Refresh: 8;URL=/cdn-cgi/l/chk_jschl?pass=1431437901.815-Ym1g5qTodK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Server: cloudflare-nginx
CF-RAY: 1e5685ed559606ee-LHR
```

Here is my code :

```
public static string GetCookie(string link)
{
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://hornystress.me");
    request.Proxy = WebProxy.GetDefaultProxy();
    request.Timeout *= 100;
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    return response.Headers.Get("Set-Cookie");
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Any one? Please its important

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was the the website normal response is `Error code 503` with a cookie that i want... so the compiler throws a `WebException` error;wich i should catch...

```
    public static string GetCookie()
    {
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://hornystress.me");
        request.Proxy = WebProxy.GetDefaultProxy();
        request.Timeout *= 100;
        string cookie;
         WebResponse response;
        try
        {
          response  = request.GetResponse();
          cookie = response.Headers.Get("Set-Cookie");
        }
        catch (WebException we)
        {
           cookie=we.Response.Headers.Get("Set-Cookie");
        }
        return cookie;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you're doing may look like an attack against the site & it is triggering a security feature. You might want to ask the site owner to whitelist the IP(s) the calls are being made from.

Comment: I'm trying to get the same response as in fiddler (with the error 503), i made the web request but cant read the response.. The app crashes..

Answer (score 0):

It's Cloudflare security, designed to stop the exact thing you're trying to do. You won't be able to access that site using a script.